# Calculate a given indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the following integral:
$$\int x \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} dx$$

I've tried using the substitution rule, but got nothing.

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try subsituting?

Comment: I'd start by completing the square and using trig sub

Comment: Well, I've substituted $x^2 +2x +2$, after I've rewritten the initial integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$x^2+2x+2=(x+1)^2+1$$ and we set $$t=x+1$$ then is $$dx=dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x+1)=u $ thus it changes to $\int(u\sqrt {u^2+1}-\sqrt {u^2+1})du$ both of which have a known integration.